# Python convert datetime indices (plural index) into several datetime ranges

Tags: python, datetime, indexing

I have a long list of Datetime indices:

```
index_list=DatetimeIndex(['2019-08-19 00:00:00', '2019-08-19 00:01:00',
               '2019-08-19 00:02:00', '2019-08-19 00:03:00',
               '2019-08-19 00:04:00', '2019-08-19 00:05:00',
               '2019-08-19 00:06:00', '2019-08-19 00:07:00',
               '2019-08-19 00:08:00', '2019-08-19 00:09:00',
               ...
               '2020-05-08 23:50:00', '2020-05-08 23:51:00',
               '2020-05-08 23:52:00', '2020-05-08 23:53:00',
               '2020-05-08 23:54:00', '2020-05-08 23:55:00',
               '2020-05-08 23:56:00', '2020-05-08 23:57:00',
               '2020-05-08 23:58:00', '2020-05-08 23:59:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='phenomenon_time', length=28037, freq=None)
```

the basic time difference is 1min:

```
 Timedelta('0 days 00:01:00')
```

I want to know the ranges in this index. 
for example, this is in the middle:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-08-24 23:54:00', '2019-08-24 23:55:00',
               '2019-08-24 23:56:00', '2019-08-24 23:57:00',
               '2019-08-24 23:58:00', '2019-08-24 23:59:00',
               '2019-08-26 23:00:00', '2019-08-26 23:01:00',
               '2019-08-26 23:02:00', '2019-08-26 23:03:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='phenomenon_time', freq=None)
```

as you can see, there is a gap in the time. from this, I would expect to get two ranges:

```
'2019-08-24 23:54:00' - '2019-08-24 23:59:00'
```

and

```
'2019-08-26 23:00:00' - '2019-08-26 23:03:00'
```

I don't know how many ranges there are.
the simple way is to have a loop from start to end, using current and next to check each iteration:

```
temptime=index_list[0]
for current, next in zip(index_list, index_list[1:]):
    if next-current>datetime.timedelta(minutes=1):
        print (str(temptime) + ' - ' +str(current))
        temptime=next
```

I was wondering if there was a more Pythonic way of doing it?
I don't care about getting a datetimerange object, or just a list of strings. as long as I can export it out of python.

Comment: to clarify: you consider the start of a "range" to happen whenever the delta to the previous timestamp is greater 1 minute?

Comment: I don't understand the difference.

Comment: well, have a look at my answer and let me know if that is what you meant. within a "range", the time delta is 1 minute between each element of the range. between the ranges, the time delta is greater than 1 minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you need?

```
import pandas as pd

# example df
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-08-19 00:00:00', '2019-08-19 00:01:00',
                        '2019-08-19 00:02:00', '2019-08-19 00:03:00',
                        '2019-08-19 00:04:00', '2019-08-19 00:06:00',
                        '2019-08-19 00:07:00', '2019-08-19 00:12:00',
                        '2019-08-19 00:25:00', '2019-08-19 00:30:00',
                        '2019-08-19 00:31:00', '2019-08-19 00:32:00'],
                       dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='phenomenon_time', freq=None)

s = idx.to_series() # cast to Series so we can use .diff()

# start is whenever diff to previous is > 1 min. use boolean mask to get resp. entries from s.
# need to prepend first entry of the series (iloc[0]) since diff won't catch that.
starts = pd.Series([s.iloc[0]] + s[s.diff() > '1min'].to_list())
# starts
# 0   2019-08-19 00:00:00
# 1   2019-08-19 00:06:00
# 2   2019-08-19 00:12:00
# 3   2019-08-19 00:25:00
# 4   2019-08-19 00:30:00

# to get the ends of the periods, shift the mask by one.
# need to add last entry of the series (iloc[-1]) since diff won't catch that either.
ends = pd.Series(s[(s.diff() > '1min').shift(periods=-1).fillna(False)].to_list() + [s.iloc[-1]])
# ends
# 0   2019-08-19 00:04:00
# 1   2019-08-19 00:07:00
# 2   2019-08-19 00:12:00
# 3   2019-08-19 00:25:00
# 4   2019-08-19 00:32:00
```